# If $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ in $H^1$, is it true that $f_n\rightharpoonup f$ and $f_n'\rightharpoonup f'$ in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, weak-convergence

If we are talking about strong convergence, then this is true and obvious. I was wondering if it's true for weak convergence. Seems like a simple question but I have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a sequence $f_n \in H^1$ converges weakly then $f_n$ converges strongly in $L^2$ and $f'_n$ converges weakly in $L^2$. Strong convergence of $f_n$ in $L^2$ follows from compactness of inclusion $H^1 \rightarrow L^2$. Weak convergence of $f'_n$ follows from continuity of operator that takes derivative $H^1 \rightarrow L^2$, $f \rightarrow f'$ (continuous operator preserves weak convergence).

If $f_n \in H^1$ converges weakly then $f'_n \in L^2$ may not converge strongly. The counterexample is $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sin (nx) \in H^1(0,2 \pi)$ (weakly converges to zero in $H^1$). $f'_n = \cos(nx) \in L^2$ converges weakly to zero in $L^2$ (but not converges strongly).

Comment: On bounded domains we have compact inclusion. What about unbounded domains?